# Automatizar posición de imágenes

Tags: mysql, laravel

Estoy realizando una galería de imágenes, pero quiero automatizar la posición de las imágenes sin tener que estarlo escribiendo yo.

Mi intensión es que al momento de añadir una nueva imagen automáticamente se le coloque el siguiente numero y si se elimina alguna imagen, se recorran las demás

Es decir: si cuento con 3 imágenes y elimino la imagen 2, la tercer imagen tome la posición 2 y así sucesivamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por el momento solo cuento con el código de `store`

```
public function store ($request) 
{

  try {

    $carbon = new Carbon();

    $banner = $request->file('banner_image');
    $bannerName = md5($carbon->timestamp.rand()).'.'.$banner->extension();

    $image = new Images();
    $image->fill([
      'image_name' => $bannerName
    ])->save();

    $path_to_folder       = '/assets/images/gallery/';
    $public_path          = public_path().$path_to_folder;
    $banner->move($public_path, $bannerName);

    return [
      'status'    => 201,
      'title'     => 'Perfecto',
      'message'   => 'La imagen se ha guardado con exito',
      'type'      => 'success',
      'image'     => $image
    ];

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    return [
      'status'  => 401,
      'title'   => 'Error',
      'message' => 'Al parecer hay un problema por favor intentalo mas tarde',
      'type'    => 'error',
      'error'   => $e
    ];
  }

}
```

Comment: Agrega lo que lleves al momento por favor, así como un ejemplo mínimo sobre el que podamos trabajar

Comment: @BetaM ya actualice mi pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Realmante falta informacion porque solo muestras que estas guardando una imagen pero te dejo un ejemplo funcional de como podrias hacerlo es una logica simple aun asi cualquier duda comenta.

```
$product = Product::find($id);
        $images =$product->images;
        $imagesLeft = collect();
        $imagesRigth = collect();
        foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
            if ($key%2 == 0)
            {
                $imagesLeft->push($image);
            }
            else
            {
                $imagesRigth->push($image);
            }
        }
        return view('products.show')->with(compact('product', 'imagesLeft', 'imagesRigth'));
```

Todo lo que realiza es tomar todas las imagenes de un producto en tu caso serian "banners" , y recorre agrega las imagenes a una coleccion de objetos, en la vista, solo tendrias que  recorrer con un foreach en las columnas correspondientes